# How to set Button text in arabic for multiple file upload using uploadify?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I want to use multiple file upload in Arabic Language hence I should display Button text in Arabic. I have tried this peace of code.

```
$("#<%=FUAttachments.ClientID %>").uploadify({

        'uploader': '../Assets/Admin/JS/uploadify.swf',

        'cancelImg': '../Assets/Admin/JS/cancel.png',

        'buttonText':  'استعراض الملفات',

        // Rest of the code
    });
```

Button text should display in arabic. But it displays numbers instead of arabic text in button.

Could you suggest me how to implement the code for changing the text of button in arabic?

Comment: Is it in .NET ? 
#<%=FUAttachments.ClientID %> Hope its a button or link? Why don't you change the label of the control.

Comment: Yes it is file upload control in asp.net.

Comment: You can remove this 'buttonText':  'استعراض الملفات' , then put the label in the control itselft ? is it possible . I don't know about .NET controls.Hope you will get help from someother guys.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/JsGjc/

Comment: @darshanags I want exactly the same. But when I execute it, it displays numbers instead of arabic text.

Comment: what is your doc type? and have you set your document charset?

Comment: Yes I have set the document charset in master page. And it is working fine in all pages.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. Is the upload button text showing up in Arabic now?

Comment: @darshanags no, it displays number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25936/discussion-between-darshanags-and-azhar-mansuri)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot localize (read change) the file upload dialog box. Its client side and the browser language depends upon the client's OS language.

you can test it yourself open the run window (window key + r) and type `intl.cpl`

a window will appear infront of you, select "Keyboard and Languages" > "Change Keyboard"

here select the language other than english and you will see that your browser language will change unless you have explicitly specified the browser language

Comment: It is not an answer. I don't want to change my language globally. I just wanted to change button text in Arabic language. Rest of content will be in English.